# Is there a relationship between CPU(cores) and Memory(RAM)?

Tags: performance, memory, containers, cpu

I'm finding a way to get a relationship between cpu and memory allocated to a container (micro service). The performance and the utilization of these two metrics could depend on the task of the service. Anyone has an idea whether there's a way to get a fair relationship between these two metrics by either defining heuristics or not ?

Comment: There is no relationship. A task might use almost no CPU and tons of memory, or it might heavily use CPU but not require much memory. It is entirely task-dependent.

Comment: Thanks. Same thing I've observed so far. But under some heuristics will there be a possibility of having a relationship?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between them. They play an entirely different role. CPU does computing while RAM holds the data. There is possibility that some tasks may extensively use CPU but require least memory and vice versa is also possible.

Comment: Agree with that. But is there a way to get one metric (performance) considering the amount of RAM and Memory of a particular machine (let's say a container?)